# Sensorless FOC position observer error

Tags: control, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am designing my own FOC (field oriented control) system, and I am trying to implement sensorless control. I have successfully implemented sensored FOC with my system on two different motors using custom magnetic encoders. I decided to implement the sensorless position estimator described in this paper as a starting point:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5454335

The observer is described in equation (9) of the paper, and is computed directly using motor current measurements, and pre-computed motor constants. I'm restating it here:

\$\dot{\hat{x}}= y_{12} + \frac{\gamma}{2}(\hat{x}-Li_{\alpha,\beta})(\Phi^2- |\hat{x} - Li_{\alpha,\beta}|^2  \$

Where \$\gamma\$ is the controller gain, \$y_{12} \, , \, i_{\alpha,\beta}\$ are measured and \$ L, \Phi\$ are motor constants. I approximate the state variable \$\hat{x}\$ by estimating the integral of the observer output:

\$ \hat{x} \approx \sum{\dot{\hat{x}}}\ dt\$

Where dt is the time between concurrent calls of the observer. The variable \$\hat{x}\$ is defined as:

\$ x = Li_{\alpha,\beta} + \Phi \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta \\ \sin\theta \end{bmatrix} \$

Which means that the encoder position \$\theta\$ can be finally computed from \$\hat{x}\$:

\$ \theta = atan2( x_2 - Li_{\beta} \, , \, x_1 - Li_{\alpha}) \$

I am able to run the observer while commuting my motor using the encoder, and print the observer and encoder theta in matlab (shown below). The observer seems to track the motor position fairly well, but when I start using the observer position after a few seconds of using the encoder, my motor starts vibrating in place/stops spinning. I've simulated the same observer in matlab/simulink and got results good enough to use the simulated observer theta for commutation.

I've also tried introducing errors in the same range (.1-.3 radians) to my encoder and it isn't enough to stop motor commutation. I've tried tuning the observer gain, but so far I haven't been able to get better tracking than what is depicted in the image below.

I'm running this on an STM32F0 microcontroller, and using the DRV8323 for mosfet gate driving and current shunt amplification.

It seems to me that the observer theta *should* be good enough to use for commutation, but in practice it is not. How should I approach solving this issue?

[image]

Edit: updated the plot with a slower motor speed for readability (motor speed is approximately 5Hz), and added error.

Comment: "FOC" was used but not defined.

Comment: Field Oriented Control ...in other words no external position indicators, just using the back EMF from the motor. Typically done by driving two  phases on a BLDC and 'listening' to one for positional feedback: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra588/spra588.pdf

Comment: @JackCreasey Not exactly. What you describe is the "sensorless" thing. FOC by itself is about generating continuously rotating magnetic field by controlling two orthogonal current components.

Comment: @JackCreasey in FOC, all 3 phases are energized continuously. Position sensing using the bemf of an un-energized phase is not possible. I believe some types of observers estimate bemf (Luenberger-type)

Comment: The only way I understand you can do this while driving all three phases is to sense the current waveform and from this extrapolate the BEMF.

Comment: Can you define your acceptance criteria in a block diagram and show error in results . What you show seems like a hysteresis induced sawtooth with unequal gain for each polarity.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist My acceptance criteria at this point is informal; I just want an estimate that is 'accurate enough' to spin the motor. I have read that error between 3-15 degrees is acceptable in practice

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the initial observer state when you switch from encoder to observer. Have you tried just using observer from the start? Instead of switching to it mid experiment. The signals shown look just fine and should not be the cause of issues.

Comment: How do you limit acceleration?

Comment: @VicenteCunha I have tried using the observer from the start. This observer is proven not to operate properly at 0 speed in the paper, so I think I have to give it some initial velocity. The switching is time based, maybe there is a way to switch it where the disturbance is mitigated?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I do not limit the acceleration, currently I am only tracking torque with FOC. Since there is no load and small inertia, it hits steady state velocity relatively quickly

Comment: With a load if you don’t limit acceleration it may slip or stall

Comment: I think rotor friction and inertia provides enough load at the torque I am tracking. If I use the encoder to update park/inverse park transforms, it spins indefinitely at the same speed, but if I use the observer to track the same torque, it immediately stops spinning and vibrates back and forth.

Comment: Since you say that the observer is not appropriate for 0 speeds, I would recommend a different approach: either use an adaptive observer for different speeds, go for a kalman filter approach, or take into consideration model uncertainty.

Comment: An idea that could work: before switching to observer, start its calculations in an open-loop manner (still using encoder for feedback), and only switch from encoder to observer after the estimation error reaches steady state. However, this is not a perfect sensorless solution.

Comment: @VicenteCunha that is what I was doing in the above diagram. the observer output is in blue and the encoder angle is in orange. I ran the motor with the encoder for a few seconds while also running the observer before switching over to the observer.

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the paper in your question.

Comment: FOC implies a feedback controller to me. Maybe the dynamics of the observer model doesn't fit well with the time constants in the feedback loop?

Comment: not sure what you mean by time constants, but this observer does operate by minimizing the error of the magnetic flux linkage constant. I'm suspecting a combination of: bad estimate of that constant, current measurement error, and lower than necessary controller bandwidth.